# Apply a transform to a UIImage when drawing

Tags: ios, uiimage, quartz-graphics, cgaffinetransform

Trying to superimpose a smaller image which may be scaled or rotated onto a lager image:

```
+ (UIImage*)addToImage:(UIImage *)baseImage newImage:(UIImage*)newImage atPoint:(CGPoint)point transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);
    [baseImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height)];

    [newImage drawAtPoint:point];
    //How would I apply the transform?

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return result;
}
```

How would I apply the CGAffineTransform to newImage in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the CoreImage framework, this allows transformations on `CIImage` instances. For example:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = ...;
CIImage* coreImage = newImage.CIImage;

if (!coreImage) {
    coreImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage];
}

coreImage = [coreImage imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
newImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:coreImage];
```

You'll need to ensure that after calling `.CIImage`, that is isn't `nil`. This will occur if the `UIImage` was initialised with a `CGImage`. If this is the case, then you'll need to allocate a `CIImage` yourself with the appropriate initialiser.

Comment: I could not find a reference to `imageFromCIImage`, where is it?

Comment: Sorry, should be `imageWithCIImage:`, was a typo. I have updated the answer.

Comment: how about the orientation? its broken after the tranform!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
+ (UIImage*) addToImage:(UIImage *)baseImage newImage:(UIImage*)newImage atPoint:(CGPoint)point transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [baseImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height)];

//    [newImage drawAtPoint:point];  draw without applying the transformation

    CGRect originalRect = CGRectMake(point.x,
                                     point.y,
                                     newImage.size.width,
                                     newImage.size.height);


    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, originalRect, newImage.CGImage);

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This draws the newImage upside down.